# How do I use BeautifulSoup to move tag contents from one soup to a template soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a template like this:

```
 <html><body><div id="here"></div></body></html>
```

and an input HTML like this

```
 <html><body>COMPLEX HTML</body></html>
```

where COMPLEX_HTML is a lot of sub tags (it's clean -- validates)

I'm trying to move just the HTML inside the body tag of the input HTML into the `#here div` in the template, to get this

```
 <html><body><div id="here">COMPLEX HTML</div></body></html>
```

I tried:

```
t = BeautifulSoup("<html><body><div id=\"here\"></div></body></html>")
pc = t.find("div", id="here")
s = BeautifulSoup(open("complex.html"))

# this prints every tag in body
for b in s.body.contents:
  print b.name

# this prints only some of the tags
for b in s.body.contents:
  print b.name
  pc.append(b)
```

`pc` ends up with every other tag from `s.body`

It's as if appending `b` moves the iterator forward.  How do I take HTML structure from one soup and put it in another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it something like this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<html><body><div id="here"></div></body></html>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
div = soup.find("div", id="here")

html2 = """<html><body><script   src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script src="//cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=283ea58c715b"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="//cdn.ss  tatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?   v=71d362e7c10c">
           </body></html>"""

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html2)
value = soup1.body.extract()

div.append(value)
print div
```

And the output is :

```
<div id="here"><body><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=283ea58c715b"></script>
<link href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=71d362e7c10c" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css">
</link></body></div>
```

If you want the content inside the  `body` you can do it something like this instead :

```
#the above same lines

soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html2)
value = soup1.body.extract()

div.append(value)
# replaces a tag with whatever’s inside that tag.
div.body.unwrap()
print div
```

And the output is :

```
<div id="here"><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.sstatic.net/Js/stub.en.js?v=283ea58c715b"></script>
<link href="//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=71d362e7c10c" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css">
</link></div>
```

Comment: The issue is the body tag inside the div.  I am trying to take everything inside a body tag, and stuff that into a div in a template (not including the body tag itself)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so append(tag) removes the tag from its structure, so in effect, the next tag gets skipped (since you are altering the structure while iterating)

I used this

```
bc = soup.body.contents
while len(bc) > 0:
    pc.append(bc[0])
```

Still removes bc[0] from the body, but I am not depending on the structure not being altered.

This is ok for me, because I don't need the original soup.